# What is an antonym for "prior" that is shorter than "subsequent?"

Tags: antonyms, synonyms

In a software application, two drop-down lists are presented. The first is labeled "relative period" and is populated with "Prior," "Current," and "Subsequent." The second list is labeled "interval" and is populated with month names, quarter names, and other intervals like "year to date."

I am hoping to find a shorter, less formal-sounding alternative to "subsequent." Does one exist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names for program thingies is off-topic according to our Help Center.

Comment: @tchrist Choosing names for variables and classes in computer code is definitely off-topic, but I don't see why asking for suggestions for a label in the user interface would be off-topic.

Comment: That said, I'm feeling a bit confused by this UI, or at least your description of it. I suggest that you get the concept reviewed on [ux.se].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we use back and forward instead of backward and forward?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197012/why-do-we-use-back-and-forward-instead-of-backward-and-forward)

Comment: `++` and `--` are pretty short.

Comment: Later, after, following, trailing, next, belated, delayed.

Comment: You could also try the User Experience stack exchange.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Almost every time I've given or seen these sorts of navigation options (*e.g.* Google Calendar), the options are **Previous** and **Next**. It is often unnecessary to even provide **Current**; just provide a label to indicate what the currently selected period is.

Comment: This sounds best to my ear. "Previous" also sounds more proximate to "current" than "prior" to me, which is good.

Answer (score 6):

How about "following"? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/prior

Theoretically, "later" or "after" are shorter, but they don't seem to convey the right meaning in that context to me.

Comment: 'After' isn't an adjective in this sense. 'Later' is as reasonable as 'subsequent': both adjectives require reference.

Comment: This sounds pretty good too - "Prior Quarter," "Current Quarter," "Following Quarter" feels pretty parallel.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the shortened *post-* for the opposite of prior.

E.g.,

"Prior to his education, he made very little money. However, the post-MBA scholar quickly found a steady job."

Answer (score 3):

How about **future**?

*Prior - Current - Future*

Comment: "Future" implies that the choice is relative to _now_, and not some other reference point.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [*posterior*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/posterior) is somewhat shorter (although *subsequent* is not a terribly long word, either). To boot, it is level with *prior* in style.

Rather rich in meaning, though.

Answer (score 1):

Options for times in the past:

> - *past*
> - *back*
> - *last*

Options for times in the future:

> - *coming*
> - *forward*
> - *ahead*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [latter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/latter), which goes well with prior as the two sound alike.  The definition being:

> > **Latter**
> >
> > **adjective**
> >
> > 1. being the second mentioned of two (distinguished from former): 
> >        "I prefer the latter offer to the former one."
> > 2. more advanced in time; later: 
> >        "in these latter days of human progress."

It can easily refer to an item in the list that comes after another, as well as an event that happens after another.